# text search with pymongo trouble with double quotes

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm trying to do a text search in a python file with pymongo using the code:

```
mensajes = db.m
mensajes.find({"$text":{"$search": query}},{'message':1}))
query= "origami \"Pasó algo.\"-pingüino"
```

And the return is []. But if I use the same query in mongo shell it works perfectly. If I use:

```
query= 'origami \'Pasó algo.\'-pingüino'
```

Instead of the same query with double quotes, I get results from the python files, but they are incorrect. I don´t understand why the results are different if the query is the same, I´m just using simple quotes. (The text search I want to do is find the message that contains Pasó algo, doesn´t contains pingüino, and it can contain origami or not)

Comment: Single and double quotes are not the same, ergo your queries are different.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that you have applied [text-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index) to the key.

pymongo gets confused when you use `Escape-Sequences` in text search.

I would suggest you try out `Triple-Quotes` string declaration or strictly string declaration.

**Strict string declaration:**

```
query= r"origami 'Pasó algo.'-pingüino"
```

**Triple quotes declaration**

```
query= """origami 'Pasó algo.'-pingüino"""
```